# how can I make an if loop in python to say " if something (in this case 1/1) exist in one of my column (in my case 10)?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a file like this:

```
Chr10   31      .       T       C       35.1    .       DP=7;AF1=1;CI95=1,1;DP4=0,0,7,0;MQ=23;FQ=-48    GT:PL:GQ        1/1:68,21,0:39**
Chr10   445     .       G       T       34      .       DP=23;AF1=0.5;CI95=0.5,0.5;DP4=7,5,6,3;MQ=19;FQ=12.3;PV4=1,6.2e-08,1,0.27       GT:PL:GQ        0/1:64,0,39:42
Chr10   447     .       A       C       93      .       DP=26;AF1=1;CI95=1,1;DP4=0,0,13,8;MQ=19;FQ=-90  GT:PL:GQ        1/1:126,63,0:99
Chr10   449     .       G       C       5.46    .       DP=28;AF1=0.4999;CI95=0.5,0.5;DP4=9,4,6,4;MQ=23;FQ=7.8;PV4=0.69,4.3e-08,0.037,1 GT:PL:GQ        0/1:34,0,130:34
Chr10   481     .       C       T       67      .       DP=55;AF1=0.5;CI95=0.5,0.5;DP4=17,22,10,5;MQ=25;FQ=70;PV4=0.22,1.5e-07,1,1      GT:PL:GQ        0/1:97,0,152:99
```

and I would like to make a loop that finds all the lines which have `1/1`in their 10th column.

This is the script that I wrote:

```
pilup= open ("libary_ts.sorted.pilup", "rb+")
with open ("select.txt", "wb+") as ch:
  for data in ch:
    e=data.split()
    if e[9] == "1/1":
```

but I know it's wrong since the `if e[9] ==` means if the column 10 has the exact 1/1, and as you can see in the sample data that I put I always has somthing like this:

```
1/1:213,60,0:99
```

or

```
0/1:43,0,118:46
```

I just wanted to know what should I use to make this if statement work properly? Is there any symbol which says contain? I couldn’t find it anywhere! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To format code (or raw input files) on stackoverflow, select it and press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it can appear anywhere in the column:

```
if "1/1" in e[9]:
  ...
```

If it must appear at the start of the column as in your example:

```
if e[9].startswith("1/1"):
  ...
```

Alternatively, if the column always contains colon-separated values:

```
if e[9].split(':')[0] == "1/1":
  ...
```

The last one is the strictest of the three, and would be my personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for your really complete answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `open ("select.txt", "wb+")` will delete the file's contents. I assume you're iterating over `pilup`.

You can use the [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) to test whether `1/1` occurs anywhere in the tenth element:

```
if "1/1" in e[9]:
```

Alternatively, use [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check whether the tenth element, well, starts with `"1/1"`:

```
if e[9].startswith("1/1"):
```

Answer (score 0):

If `1/1` will always be at the start of that column, you can use the `startswith` string method:

```
if e[9].startswith("1/1")
```